# return data from xml using php

Tags: php, xml, soap, wsdl

I have a MindBody API [link](https://api.mindbodyonline.com/0_5/ClassService.asmx?WSDL) (`https://api.mindbodyonline.com/0_5/ClassService.asmx?WSDL`)
 from it i wish to fetch the data using php. I can get the class schedule by the following code:

```
$parameters = array(
    'StartDateTime' => date('Y-m-d'), 
    'EndDateTime'   => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('today + 7 days'))
);
$data = $notASoapClient->GetClasses($parameters);

if (!empty($data['GetClassesResult']['Classes']['Class'])) 
{
    $classes = $notASoapClient->makeNumericArray($data['GetClassesResult']['Classes']['Class']);
    print_r($classes);
}
```

But I am not able to fetch `GetClassVisits` data, which will have the list of students enrolled in every class. Can anyone tell how I can do so?

Comment: From the reactions of your answer and because `makeNumericArray` is not a request in the webservice, it looks like that `$mb` is not a SoapClient. This perhaps was hidden in the question so far, I changed the variable name to clearly state that. Perhaps the code is hidden and the question just not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the wsdl you linked to there seems to be a method `GetClassVisits`. Since you already know how to call one method in the webservice (`$data = $mb->GetClasses(array('StartDateTime'=>date('Y-m-d'), 'EndDateTime'=>date('Y-m-d', strtotime('today + 7 days'))))`) you should be able to call the `GetClassVisits`. From what I've seen it takes one `GetClassVisitsRequest` which contains one `ClassID`:

```
$mb->GetClasses(array('ClassID'=>12345));
```

Comment: i am still getting details of class only not the clients enrolled in a class, and in your code also u have showed for a single class, I wish to get all the classes with all the students in it, can u please provide a detailed code, i am having a big difficulty in fetching this particular data

Comment: @sammy The same logic applies to all available methods, so you should either read the API doc if you have it or infer the other methods from the WSDL.